# Borel-measurable function of Markov process is not necessary Markov process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(X_t, t \in \mathbb{R})$ be a real Markov process, $R \subset \mathbb{R}_+$. $h_t$ is Borel-measurable bijection and its inverse is also Borel-measurable. Then $Y_t = (h_t(X_t), t)$ is also a Markov process.

My attempt: 
Consider one of the equal definitions of a Markov process: $\forall m, \forall s_1 < ... < s_m < s < t, \forall f$ - bounded Borel function $ E(f(X_t)|X_s, X_{s_m}, ..., X_{s_1}) = E(f(X_t)|X_s)$. Then let's take any $f$ and $f(h(X_t))$. Composition of Borel functions is a Borel function, so the process is Markov.

But where to use the fact that h is a bijection?

Comment: You would need to show $E(f(h_t(X_t)) \mid h_s(X_s), h_{s_m}(X_{s_m}), \dots, h_{s_1}(X_{s_1})) = E(f(h_t(X_t)) \mid h_s(X_s))$ - which is not the same as showing $E(f(h_t(X_t)) \mid X_s, X_{s_m},\dots,X_{s_1}) = E(f(h_t(X_t)) \mid X_s)$.

Comment: But does this problem appear if I use just the standard definition? $E(f(X_T) | F_s) = E(f(X_t)|X_s). Just place there h(...) and Borel function saves sigma-algebras.

Comment: The Borel function will not preserve sigma-algebras! What if $h$ is a constant function? Then the sigma-algebra generated by $X$ is *not* the sigma-algebra generated by $h(X)$. But if $h$ is a bijection...